android.R.id.shareText value doesn't match the actual menu item value
I'm trying to remove (or not to add) build-in share item in Android WebView context menu.
But for some reason android.R.id.shareText yields different value, not one which corresponds to the actual Share menu item. Debugging the code below yields the following results:

android.R.id.shareText == 16908341


item.getItemId() == 151060738

As result, I can't delete build-in share item, unless I hardcode the ID value (151060738), but I'm not sure that it will work on all devices (if at all).
Why IDs don't match?
    @Override
    public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
        if (mActionMode == null) {
            mode.hide(1);
            mActionMode = mode;
            Menu menu = mode.getMenu();

            // Collect all existing items
            List<MenuItem> defaultItems = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
                defaultItems.add(menu.getItem(i));
            }

            // Clear the menu
            menu.clear();

            // Add custom items
            menu.add(0, R.id.search, 0, R.string.search);
            menu.add(0, R.id.findOnPage, 0, R.string.findOnPage);
            menu.add(0, R.id.share, 0, R.string.share);

            menu.findItem(R.id.search).setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                getSelectedText(this::openWord);
                return true;
            });

            menu.findItem(R.id.findOnPage).setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                getSelectedText(this::openFindOnPage);
                return true;
            });

            menu.findItem(R.id.share).setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
                getSelectedText(text -> {
                    String url = AppConfig.shareUrlPrefix + Utils.urlEncode(text);
                    shareText(url);
                });
                return true;
            });

            // If you want you may inflate your custom menu instead of adding manually:
            //mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.text_context_menu, menu);

            // Add all default items
            int i = 1;
            for (MenuItem item: defaultItems) {
                if (item.getItemId() != android.R.id.shareText) {
                    menu.add(item.getGroupId(), item.getItemId(), i++, item.getTitle());
                }
            }


        }
        super.onActionModeStarted(mode);
    }


"unless I hardcode the ID value (151060738), but I'm not sure that it will work on all devices (if at all)" -- resource IDs vary by build, other than those in the framework (such as android.R.id.shareText). "Why IDs don't match?" -- since the WebView implementation varies by device, and they are mostly proprietary, we cannot really answer that. Apparently, they did not use android.R.id.shareText but instead used a string resource defined within their own app.
